# Motivic Galois correspondence

Tags: galois-theory, motives

Is there a Galois correspondence in motivic Galois theory ? If so, is there a mathematical work on this correspondence that i can find on the net ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In any Tannakian category, including the conjectural Tannakian category of motives, there is a Galois correspondence between subcategories stable under subobjects, quotients, duals, sums, and tensor products (I might be missing a condition there) and normal subgroups. I don't know how much more there is to say there so I don't know if anyone has studied this.

Comment: @Will: should the notion of L-rig introduced in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372349/are-there-infinitely-many-l-rigs be categorized, would it give rise to a Tannakian category and that way "explain" why L-functions of arithmetic interest ought to be motivic? I can ask a separate question if needed.

Comment: I know very little about this matters; yet my impression that needs some Langlands-type conjectures to make reasonable(??) L-functions motivic. And several people studied the motivic Galois group. This is a rather complicated thing. and Joseph Ayoub is a specialist.