# Automorphisms of the ring of periods

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, l-functions, automorphism-groups, periods

The set of periods $\mathcal{P}$ introduced by Kontsevich and Zagier forms a ring, see for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(algebraic_geometry).
Moreover J. Wan introduced in 2011 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2273 the notion of degree of a periods.

My question deals with ring automorphisms of $\mathcal{P}$ preserving the degree. Necessarily such automorphisms preserve the set of algebraic numbers, and it is easy to see that the identity and the complex conjugation are such automorphisms. My question is: are there any others?

Moreover can one associate bijectively to a given period $p$ an L-function $L_{p}$ of same degree belonging to some L-rig as defined in [Are there infinitely many L-rigs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372349/are-there-infinitely-many-l-rigs) so that the complex conjugate of $p$ is mapped to the dual of $L_{p}$?

That way, maybe we could prove that a given number like $e+\pi$ or $\gamma$ is not a period by proving no L-function can be associated to it.

Comment: Since Wan’s paper defining these degrees could not provide concrete examples of periods with degree $\ge 3$, any proof-strategy relying on that notion seems hopeless.

Comment: 21 hours before the bounty expires. Even a partial answer would be nice.